# symfony factories.yml issue for modules

Tags: configuration, module, symfony1, settings, action

I need to load default factories.yml with default settings, but only for one module in my application:

```
frontend:
  config:
    factories.yml
    settings.yml
  modules:
    ajax:
      action:
      config:
        factories.yml
      templates:
    etc:
      action:
      templates:
    etc2:
      action:
      templates:
```

I just need to load for the ajaxmodule a special factories.yml for increase speed issues.
I read something that its not possible, but gives there any solutions for this issue?
I really need help, i dont get it :(
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put your custom factories.yml in apps/your_app_name/modules/your_module_name/config instead of apps/your_app_name/config ?
This should override your default factiories.yml in context of your custom module (the same as for example view.yml)

Comment: ofc this is what i tried, i read in docu that it is not possible to change factories for a module, just for the controler of a application.